# How many do we have?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

A Mobile Friendly Question according to [the recent Monthly Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/monthly-topic-challenge-12-mobile-friendly-puzzles)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

*I* HAVE ONE

> straight line in I

*ROD* HAS THREE

> straight lines in R and D

*DICK* has FIVE

> straight lines in D, I and K

*WE* HAVE

> eight straight lines in 'WE'

Comment: How do you get 3 from ROD - I see a vertical stroke in R, and one in D, but everything else is curved to me.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I guess it’ll depend on your font but in OP’s image the R’s diagonal leg is straight as well.

Comment: But there is also a horizontal line in the letter R, which would give ROD 4 lines.  Or is that only me seeing it?

Comment: @nuggethead: Only you ;) The upper left part of the R is generally understood as being a semi-circle. Now, as flat earthers have realized, if you take a small enough arc of a circle, it looks like a straight line, and here I expect that the additional diagonal line forming the bottom left of the R accentuates the impression... but look at the curvature of the semi-circle and note the symmetry between top and bottom.